# Changing Position of Dropdown Menu

Tags: html, css

I have a dropdown menu in my website which I want to be exactly in line with the "Resources" tab (which opens up the dropdown menu when I hover over it). I have tried adding margins to the `ul` inside the "Resources" `li`, but it isn't changing the styling the way I want it to. Am I entering the CSS in the wrong selector or even using the wrong properties?

Here is my HTML and CSS:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: orange;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
}

nav p {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 55px;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

nav ul {
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative; /* we can add absolute position in subcategories */
  padding-right: 1em;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  font-family: arial;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 22px 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


nav ul li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 5px; /* Spacing so that hover color does not take up entire chunk */
  border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
}

nav ul li:hover ul {
  /* This means when li is hovered, we want the unordered list inside list item to do something. */
  display: block;
}


nav ul li ul li{
   width: 130px; /* increases width so that all text can be fit */
  border-radius: 4px;
}

nav ul li ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #ADD8E6;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <p> The Novel Column </p>
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="#"> Resources </a>
      <ul> 
        <li> <a href="#"> Book Reviews </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#"> Quotes and Principles </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#"> Community Aid </a> </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#"> About Us </a> </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Think you just need to add `left:0px` to this `nav ul li ul` if you want to change the left positioning you can add or take away some left pixels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add

```
nav ul li ul {
  left: 50%;
  right: auto;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

`left: 50%` positions the left edge of the dropdown in the center of its parent. Then `translateX(-50%)` moves it to the left by half of the dropdown's width. Lastly `right: auto` ensures that the dropdown's width doesn't get messed up.

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/7Lzb8u6t/

Comment: Your answer does move the dropdown right a bit, but I would like the first letter of each word in the dropdown to be directly in line with the "Resources" tab. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Add `translateX()` CSS property to move your box, you can play with `transform value` and match your exact location,

for more information `1 rem = 16px;`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: orange;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
}

nav p {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 55px;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

nav ul {
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative; /* we can add absolute position in subcategories */
  padding-right: 1em;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  font-family: arial;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 22px 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


nav ul li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 5px; /* Spacing so that hover color does not take up entire chunk */
  border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
  transform: translateX(3rem);
}

nav ul li:hover ul {
  /* This means when li is hovered, we want the unordered list inside list item to do something. */
  display: block;
}


nav ul li ul li{
   width: 130px; /* increases width so that all text can be fit */
  border-radius: 4px;
}

nav ul li ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #ADD8E6;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <p> The Novel Column </p>
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="#"> Resources </a>
      <ul> 
        <li> <a href="#"> Book Reviews </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#"> Quotes and Principles </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#"> Community Aid </a> </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#"> About Us </a> </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```